# How do I manipulate size of point symbols in Legend for ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, legend

I have a legend where the point symbols are coming out really small, and I want to boost up their size but leave polygon and line symbols as-is.  I get that I can manipulate the polygon height and width in the properties, but i can't seem to find how to increase point size for a point feature symbol (see pic below).  Where is this in Arc Pro?

[image]

Comment: I usually create a copy of the feature layer with "_legend" added to the name, adjust the symbology until it displays correctly in the legend, then turn that layer off in the Contents (but on in the legend), and turn the original feature layer off in the legend.  This isn't a great solution since you have to manually manage the symbology of the two layers separately, but it works for me.